# is Authenticated value not being updated by login function

Tags: angular, typescript

i have an angular service that is responsible for logging in users and share authentication information with a behavior subject like so:

```js
  private isAuthenticated$ = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);
setAuthenticated(value: boolean) {
    this.isAuthenticated$.next(value)
  }

  Authenticated(): boolean {
    return this.isAuthenticated$.getValue()
  }
```

in my component I'm using the following function for logging in users and update the isAuthenticated BehaviorSubject:

```js
onSubmit() {
    let email = this.loginForm.get('email')?.getRawValue();
    let password = this.loginForm.get('password')?.getRawValue();
    this.loginSub = this.authService.login(email, password).subscribe(
      (res) => {
        this.authService.setUserBehavior();
        this.authService.setAuthenticated(true)
        this.router.navigate(['']);
      },
      (err) => {
        console.error(err);
      }
    );
  }
```

I then have a guard that should prevent logged in users from accessing certain routes

```js
canActivate(
    route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean | UrlTree> | Promise<boolean | UrlTree> | boolean | UrlTree {
    console.log(this.authService.Authenticated())
    if(this.authService.Authenticated()){
      console.log('isAuth')
      return this.router.parseUrl(this.authService.redirectTo)
    }
    console.log('isNotAuth')
    return true;
  }
```

problem here is that even if user logs in and login function kicks in, as I log the `isAuthenticated$` value inside my guard using `console.log(this.authService.Authenticated())` value is always false.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead using synchronous access to that subject, it is recommended to go into the reactive way by changing canActivate method to return an observable like this:

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthService {
  private authenticated$ = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);

  get authenticated(): boolean {
    return this.authenticated$.getValue();
  }

  get authenticatedObservable(): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.authenticated$.asObservable();
  }

  login(username: string, password: string): void {
    // perform authentication logic here
    this.authenticated$.next(true);
  }

  logout(): void {
    // perform logout logic here
    this.authenticated$.next(false);
  }
}

canActivate(
  route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
  state: RouterStateSnapshot
): Observable<boolean | UrlTree> | Promise<boolean | UrlTree> | boolean | UrlTree {
  return this.authService.authenticatedObservable.pipe(
    map((authenticated: boolean) => {
      console.log(authenticated);
      if (authenticated) {
        //...
      }
      //...
    })
  );
}
```

Comment: lthanks for the answer, ooks like this does not solve the problem is it possible that isAuthenticated is not being set because the function that performs login is actually inside the component and not inside the service?

Comment: You need to check that the guard will load after set state is done.

Comment: I noticed that if I console log the value of `isAuthenticated$` after updating it In the same function I perform the update the value is correct but the guard still sees it as false

Comment: I don't actually know what do you mean with that, I'll be grateful for a more detailed answer

Comment: Do you inject authentication service at root level, to have a single instance?

Comment: I'm injecting it in the constructor of the guard and the component

Comment: shouldn.t it be a singleton by definition?

Comment: it is depending how do you register within the injector: @Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})